# Is there a function to return the first null value of a row?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, isnull

I have the following table:

```
create table table1  
( 
    id serial, 
    workdate date,
    tanknum1 integer,
    tanknum2 integer,
    tanknum3 integer,
    tank1startingvalue float,
    tank2startingvalue float,
    tank3startingvalue float,
    tank1endvalue float,
    tank2endvalue float,
    tank3endvalue float
);
```

And I have inserted the following data:

```
insert into table1(id, workdate) values (DEFAULT, '01/12/2023');
```

Now I updated it, looking to the first null column of a sequence. For example: I run the following update:

```
update table1 set tanknum1 = 8 where id = 1;
```

Now that I have updated it once, I want to create a query to look for the first NULL column and then update it. For example: I already have the tanknum1 non-NULL, so when I update the query using date 01/12/2023 I want it to look for tanknum2 and tanknum3. Tanknum2 is NULL? Ok, then I'll change this value. tanknum2 is non-NULL? All right, let me check tanknum3. Is it null? (and so forth. The edge case is: if i get to tanknum3 and it's already non-NULL I don't want to update it)

I'm doing this to control a gas station inventory and I'm not able to upgrade the Postgre version. This information is arriving to me via .txt file, only with the tank number, date, starting and ending value.

How can I do that I PostgreSQL? (Using Postgre 9.6)

I tried to use COALESCE to do that. However, I get the exact reverse result that I'm looking for. Lacking ideas now (except to use a lot of CASE WHEN on my code - something that I'm trying not to do. Want to do something more elegant)

Comment: `Coalesce()` seems to be usable for what you described: `update table1 set col1 = coalesce(col1,'12') where id = 1;` if col1 is not null, then it remains unchanged. If it is, it's set to '12'. Problem is, if you target all columns this way, they'll all get updated independently, not just the first one. Can you provide some additional context on what it is you're trying to achieve with this? What's the actualy problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: There isn't a function to do what you've asked nor should there be. Column order has no semantic significance because a row (tuple in relational theory parlance) is an unordered set of attributes. From your post, it appears that `col1`, `col2`, etc., form a repeating group, which should not exist in a normalized database; however, there could be valid reasons to violate this guideline. If `col2` is non-NULL, must `col1` also be non-NULL? If so, then constraints should be in place to enforce that rule. Please update your post with the use case and data integrity rules.

Comment: `Using Postgre 9.6` you must be joking. That version was released back in 2016 and is EOL since 2021. Do yourself a favor and upgrade to a recent (supported) version. For identity columns, use IDENTITY: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: What should happen if `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are already all non-NULL? It's very important to consider edge cases and possible failure modes and to fully specify expected behavior. `COALESCE` is essentially syntactic sugar for a `CASE` expression to find the first non-NULL value, so it's only more elegant by virtue of brevity.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: @Zegarek the problem: I have a row with a lot of those columns (col1, col2, col3... It's a  company that i'm not a developer - can't change the database structure - and the database stores information about diesel tanks volumes). Each column saves the amount of liters of diesel stored phisically somewhere.

Don't know why they made the database like this - I agree that this database is not normalized - But I can't change it neither

Comment: @JohnH I know that there's no function for that, and I'm not looking for a function. I'm looking for a better way to solve this, rather than put a lot of "case when" on my script. You're right about this forming a repeating group, it does.

If col2 is non-NULL, must col1 also be non-NULL? Yes. 
Update your post with the use case and data integrity rules: Can you explain to me better what do you need? I'm a little bit lost about this

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm not joking. But I'm not able to change that and not the one in charge of this decision.

However, can you explain to me how a newer version could help me to solve this problem? As far as I've studied even if I upgraded Postgre to the last release version it won't be easily solvable

Comment: @JohnH I've reduced the real size of the table, just for the sake of clarity. The real table have 12 columns (for this matter. I'll update the post with the real table). In the rare case that all that columns is non-NULL there should be no other updates

Comment: @jarlh the MRE is on the question. Have you tried this on PgAdmin or PSQL?

Comment: @lamarcondes16 *"If col2 is non-NULL, must col1 also be non-NULL? Yes."* It doesn't sound like it changes much about how this would be solved but if that's the case, you should have a constraint to actually enforce this and/or a (constraint) trigger to maintain that. I take that the logic is you're filling up and emptying the tanks in a First-In-Last-Out manner, and your desired update logic means pumping the fuel in there, left to right. What about distributing a fixed amount of fuel up to the capacity of each tank, overflowing to the next? And same in reverse, for unloading/pumping out?

Comment: Reading the question again, this looks like an issue with the data model: How come that different columns hold the same kind of data? If you have a table holding first name and last name, you never want to put the content of one column into the other: Very different data.

Comment: @FrankHeikens that's exactly the point. I agree with you: there's a lot of colums to hold the same kind of data (the only difference is the number of the filled tank). My challenge is to use this already-existing database to work.

Comment: @Zegarek "I take that the logic is you're filling up and emptying the tanks in a FILO manner" - Kinda. I'm controlling a gas station - there's no particular order of the pumping fuel. There are like 6 really big tanks under the soil with gasoline, diesel, ethanol, and so forth. The gas station has 2 gasoline tanks, 2 diesel tanks, 1 ethanol, and 1 powered gasoline, for example. So the control is made only using the tank number. I'll change the question giving more details

Comment: @lamarcondes16 [Based on your clarifications, I fixed the edge case and aligned the naming with your updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77875590/5298879). As to the added context: 1. so 3 columns for tanks even though both the number of tanks and the number of types of tanks at a station can exceed that. Sounds like someone made a random "yup, that should be enough" call and shipped it. 2. If that's not pumping connected tanks, then I still don't really understand what business logic updating first non-null column is supposed to reflect or what problem this really solves, what's it meant for

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that you have been saddled with a poorly designed data model. Having a single column forming a repeating group is bad enough, but the having additional related columns forming repeating groups of a more complex object is much worse. Unless you're able to change the data model, I don't see an elegant way to address your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> return the first null value of a row

Turn the row into an array and [`array_position(row_array,null)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.8.1.1.1) *returns the first null value of a row*. Use that with [array `:` slicing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-MODIFYING) combined with [sub-SELECT-based `UPDATE` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-update.html) and you can avoid the extensive `case` tree.

Construct an array out of the row, slice it up to where the first `null` is, concatenate your desired element there with a [`||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE), then add the remaining slice with another `||`. [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1Ri_Mhyo):

```sql
update table1 set (tanknum1,tanknum2,tanknum3)=(
select arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]
from (select coalesce(arr[:array_position(arr,null)-1],arr)
             ||array[9]
             ||arr[array_position(arr,null)+1:] as "arr"
      from (select array[tanknum1,tanknum2,tanknum3] arr) i1
)i2)
where workdate='01/12/2023'
returning *;
```

| id | workdate | tanknum1 | tanknum2 | tanknum3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-12-01 | 8 | 9 | *null* |

You can achieve a similar effect with `jsonb` and related functions. That's just to demonstrate it's doable, not that it's a good idea. It's best to state what your actual problem is and how you see this kind of mechanism helping you arrive at a solution.

Comment: [This works fine in 9.6](https://dbfiddle.uk/8hBT8n4j). 9.5 Didn't allow omitting slice bounds, but [it can be made to work there too](https://dbfiddle.uk/yGTyfjgj). 9.4 didn't yet implement this sort of [subselect-based update syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-update.html). Still, please consider an update.

Comment: Worth noting that this sort of thing relies on all these columns having the same type. In  a `jsonb` you [can have a multi-typed array](https://dbfiddle.uk/D3UgbcWd), but since you need casting on input and output of values in a `jsonb`, you can just as well cast to `text` on the way into a regular, native `array[]` and back from it on their way out.